# Client crashes during full compile in Dynamics AX 2012 R2 CU6

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I just gave the new Contoso-demo-vm (Microsoft Dynamics AX 2012 R2 Solution Demo Package V3.0) provided by Microsoft a try.

When I tried to execute a first full compile, the client crashed after a few hours. I enabled AOT log to see when the client chrashes. After another compile I checked the log file and noticed that the problem seemed to appear during the compile of the Managed Content Items.

So I tried to compile only the Web-node. The client crashed every time. Either in somewhere in the Managed Content Items or after it finished the Managed Content Items.

I didn't change anything in the Web-node. My coworkers have the same issues.

Does anyone else have this problem? Or does anyone have an explanation or solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed CU7. Due to axbuild.exe I don't have crashes anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problems. I have the same thing in the following situations:

- Synchronizing labels with TFS
- Force synchronizing TFS
- Full compiling

All of these result in the same exception when digging deeper with WinDbg :

*ExceptionAddress: 01642ef9 (Ax32!interpret::getThisPtr+0x00000027)
ExceptionCode: c0000005 (Access violation)
ExceptionFlags: 00000000*

The access violation actually points to memory errors. And this can be seen further down the crash dump.

*PROCESS_NAME:  Ax32.exe
ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0xc0000005 - The instruction at 0x%08lx referenced memory at 0x%08lx. The memory could not be %s.*

This is as far as I could go, so unfortunately I did not find a solution for this but maybe it points people in the right direction.